# Cannot make rpm from spec file: File not found errors

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

I have a pre-made directory structure that I want to make an rpm from.
In my spec file I specify all files from that directory structure that I want to include in the rpm, and when executing rpmbuild I set the buildroot to the (from what I can tell) correct directory:

```
%files
/usr/local/bin/test/Test
/usr/local/bin/test/something.awk
/usr/share/snmp/mibs
/etc/init.d/test
```

My rpmbuild command looks like this:

```
rpmbuild --rmspec --buildroot=bin/<files dir> -bb bin/tmp.spec
```

Both the buildroot directory & location of my spec file are relative.
The directory structure looks like this:

```
/home/<me>/Projects/<project>/ <-- I execute rpmbuild from here
/home/<me>/Projects/<project>/bin/tmp.spec
/home/<me>/Projects/<project>/bin/<files dir>/ <-- All files/directories mentioned in spec file reside here
/home/<me>/Projects/<project>/bin/<files dir>/usr/local/bin/test/Test
/home/<me>/Projects/<project>/bin/<files dir>/usr/local/bin/test/something.awk
/home/<me>/Projects/<project>/bin/<files dir>/usr/share/snmp/mibs/ <-- directory with a few MIB files, which I all want to include
/home/<me>/Projects/<project>/bin/<files dir>/etc/init.d/test
```

However, when executing the rpmbuild command I get the following errors:

```
Processing files: <rpm>
error: File not found: /bin/<files dir>/usr/local/bin/test/Test
error: File not found: /bin/<files dir>/usr/local/bin/test/something.awk
error: File not found: /bin/<files dir>/usr/share/snmp/mibs
error: File not found: /bin/<files dir>/etc/init.d/test


RPM build errors:
    File not found: /bin/<files dir>/usr/local/bin/test/Test
    File not found: /bin/<files dir>/usr/local/bin/test/something.awk
    File not found: /bin/<files dir>/usr/share/snmp/mibs
    File not found: /bin/<files dir>/etc/init.d/test
```

The spec file does not contain any %prep, %build or %install directives, as the complete file structure is pre-made before building the rpm file.
I am convinced it is some small thing that I am missing, and I suspect that it is a case of rpmbuild using a different directory than I am specifying.
I've been toying around with the buildroot & _topdir directives, both with relative & absolute paths, but to no avail...

Comment: replace `<files dir>` with an actual directory name... if you realy want to use `<files dir>`; you should at least escape the space...

Comment: <files dir> is anonymized. Of course there is an actual directory name.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that you are confused by semantics of buildroot. The `--buildroot` option and `%{buildroot}` macro points to **build root**. Let me elaborate more:

In the `%install` section you are located in directory where your sources have been extracted (this has been done by `%setup` macro in `%prep` section). Now you are should create the file/directory structure in the build root. So:

```
%install
install -d %{buildroot}/usr/local/bin/test/
cp -a something.awk  %{buildroot}/usr/local/bin/test/
```

This assume that `something.awk` was in in tar.gz file of Source0 and it was in root of that archive (there was no leading paths in that archive).

`%buildroot` is always defined. And usually is in form of `~/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/%{name}-%{version}-%{release}.$arch`. When you override it with `--buildroot=bin/<files dir>` option as in your example, then the previous script in `%install` will copy the something.awk into 'bin//usr/local/bin/test/something.awk'. Which is not error per se, but does not have sense too.If you previously copied the files into your ./bin directory, then you should know that `%{buildroot}` is usually wiped before `%install` section. So you have to copy those files into '%{buildroot}' in this section.

So what was the cause of the error? When you stated:

```
%files
/usr/local/bin/test/something.awk
```

Then rpmbuild looks for file `%{buildroot}/usr/local/bin/test/something.awk`. It does not exist so rpmbuild yield "file not found". So you are obviously missing the actions in `%install` section. If you add it there then it will work. And you can omit the `--buildroot` option too.